# Memory leak in insert in sorted linked list

Tags: c, memory-leaks, linked-list, valgrind, free

I have used a function my professor provided that inserts data (ints) in a sorted linked list.

```
void sorted_insert(int x,node_t **list)
{
  node_t *q = NULL, *pq = NULL, *new_node = NULL;

  q = *list;

  while (q && x > q->data)
  {
    pq = q;
    q = q->next;
  }

  new_node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
  new_node->data = x;
  new_node->next = q;

  if (!pq) { *list = new_node; }
  else { pq->next = new_node; }

}
```

Main calls:

```
node_t *list = NULL
sorted_insert(x,&list);
```

I have tested it by saving 100 random integers to and it is doing what is expected to , as the numbers are sorted. I later used a custom free function to free each node, like so:

```
void free_list(node_t *list)
{
  node_t *tmp = NULL;

  for (; list; list = list->next)
  {
    tmp = list;
    free(tmp);
  }
  return;
}
```

However, when I analyze the program with **valgrind**, it is showing that I am leaking memory in function sorted_insert , and to be precise, on this line: `new_node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));`

Valgrind output:

```
==9478== 160 (16 direct, 144 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==9478==    at 0x483C7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9478==    by 0x109270: sorted_insert (list_insert_sorted.c:23)
==9478==    by 0x10938D: main (list_insert_sorted.c:55)
```

Why is this happening? Is there something wrong with my free function? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** I have changed the for loop, and even thoug im not skipping nodes, im still leaking memory.

Comment: ``list = list->next;`` is executed *twice* per loop, effectively you only free every other node in the list.

Comment: @PhilippGesang Thats a mistake on my part, I have corrected it but Im still leaking...

Comment: untested: but your free function has `list` as a test condition rechecked after free, second iteration and will then not clean up everything. Also I would suggest you remove unnecessary variables and the pointer on a pointer, because simpler code is simpler to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your free iterator is skipping nodes, your loop body has `list=list->next`, and so does the iterator, so it happens twice.  you're lucky you had an even number of nodes, avoiding dereferencing a NULL pointer if you had had an odd number.

```
void free_list(node_t *list)
{
  node_t *tmp = list;

  while(tmp)
  {
    list = list->next;
    free(tmp);
    tmp = list;
  }
  return;
}
```

You then edited the code to removed the duplicate iterator, but in your edited code, after `free(tmp)`, the memory `list` points to is no longer valid (same address as `tmp` after all), and your edited code dereferences the just freed memory that `list` points to in the iterator, so try what I wrote instead.